# How to have different row heights in each section of a UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I currently have a button in the `viewForFooterInSection` of every section that when clicked, increases the height of rows 5-10 from a height of 0 to a height of 65, as seen below:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    self.moreButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    self.moreButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44);
    [self.moreButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"downarrow.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.moreButton addTarget:self action:@selector(moreButtonSelected:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [view addSubview:self.moreButton];

    return view;
}

- (void)moreButtonSelected:(id)sender {
    if (_hasPressedShowMoreButton == NO){
        self.hasPressedShowMoreButton = YES;
    }
    else if (_hasPressedShowMoreButton == YES){
        self.hasPressedShowMoreButton = NO;
    }

    [self.matchCenter reloadData];
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (_hasPressedShowMoreButton == YES){
        return 65;
    }

    else if (_hasPressedShowMoreButton == NO){
        if (indexPath.row > 3){
            return 0;
        }
        else{
            return 65;
        }
    }

}
```

This is meant to be a "show more" sort of action, so that when pressed, the rest of the rows appear, as opposed to only the first 4. The issue is, when pressing the button in the footer of a section, it expands ALL the sections to 10 rows, not only the one where the button was pressed. How can I specify just the section where the button was pressed?

**EDIT:**

I've tried following suggestions and doing it like below, but it's causing a crash with the error `'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIButton section]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f94840640b0'`.

Code:

```
- (void)moreButtonSelected:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if (_hasPressedShowMoreButton == NO){
        self.hasPressedShowMoreButton = YES;
        indexPath.section == _expandedSection;
    }
    else if (_hasPressedShowMoreButton == YES){
        self.hasPressedShowMoreButton = NO;
    }

    [self.matchCenter reloadData];
}


- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (_hasPressedShowMoreButton == YES){
        if (indexPath.section == _expandedSection){
            return 65;
        }

    }

    else if (_hasPressedShowMoreButton == NO){
        if (indexPath.row > 3){
            return 0;
        }
        else{
            return 65;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You can't use a single ivar `_hasPressedShowMoreButton`. You need to keep track of the state of the button for all sections.

Comment: @rmaddy Ah, makes sense. Mind expanding on how I can track the state of each respective button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be checking `indexPath.section == _expandedSection` as well. (Store the `indexPath.section` of your pressed more button into `_expandedSection`.)

Extend `UIButton` to allow assignment of section to it.

```
@interface MoreButton : UIButton
@property (assign) NSInteger sectionIndex;
@end

@implementation MoreButton
@end
```

Add a property to your class.

```
@property (assign) NSInteger expandedSection;
self.expandedSection = -1;
```

When you create it (and don't use `self.` to create it), assign the `sectionIndex`.

```
MoreButton *moreButton = [MoreButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
moreButton.sectionIndex = section;
[moreButton addTarget:self action:@selector(moreButtonSelected:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[view addSubview:moreButton];
```

Then in your handler:

```
- (void)moreButtonSelected:(MoreButton *)button {
  self.expandedSection = button.sectionIndex;
  [self.matchCenter reloadData];
}
```

And your height for row:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  if (indexPath.section == self.expandedSection || indexPath.row <= 3) {
    return 65;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

You could use an `NSMutableSet` for your `expandedSections` instead if you wanted to expand multiple at a time, using these lines:

```
@property (strong) NSMutableSet *expandedSections;
self.expandedSections = [NSMutableSet set];

if ([self.expandedSections containsObject:@(section)]) {
  [self.expandedSections removeObject:@(section)];
} else {
  [self.expandedSections addObject:@(section)];
}

if ([self.expandedSections containsObject:@(indexPath.section)] || indexPath.row <= 3)
```

Comment: Ah makes sense. I'm a bit confused what you mean by "Store the `indexPath.section` of your pressed more button into `_expandedSection`" though. Mind showing me an example? Thanks!

Comment: Updated my answer for you.

Comment: It's giving me the following error: `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MoreButton", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MatchCenterViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
`

Comment: It looks like you aren't correctly linking against the file that contains the `@interface MoreButton`.

Comment: This is how I'm setting up my `MatchCenterViewController.m`, am I doing something wrong? I was under the impression the file was already linked. http://i.imgur.com/JBFVg16.png

Comment: You'll also need an `@implementation` for the `MoreButton` class. It can be empty. I left it out originally because the post was getting a little long, but I've added it in for completeness.

Answer (score 1):

The problem I guess is that `indexPath.row` was not always used - when _hasPressedShowMoreButton is true, it returns 65 regardless:

```
if (_hasPressedShowMoreButton == YES){
    return 65;
} else if (_hasPressedShowMoreButton == NO){
    if (indexPath.row > 3){
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        return 65;
    }
}
```

You need to change it to something more in the following structure, and judge indexPath.row with the **outer most** if:

```
if (indexPath.row > 3) {
    //some logic here
} else {
    //some logic
}
```